# how to stop client sending messages to server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, client-server

i want to create a client server program in mfc i found some really good source code from this website: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Visual_CPP/TCP_Client_Server.html

but in this program the client sends a message to the server and the server then displays the clients ip address, port number, time, date and the message.

I don't want the client to send a message. when the client clicks the button i just want it to connect to the server. it doesn't need to do anything else. I tried removing the code that sends the message but that causes loads of compile errors.

here is some the code from client:

```
   char sbuf[1024], rbuf[1024];
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    sprintf(sbuf,"%s\r\n", (const char*) m_senddata);
    if(send(s, sbuf, strlen(sbuf), 0) == strlen(sbuf))
    {
        recv(s, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        m_recvData = rbuf;
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
    ::closesocket(s);
```

and here is some code from server:

```
        char rbuf[1024];
        recv(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        for(int i = 1024; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if(rbuf[i] == '\n' && rbuf[i - 1] == '\r')
            {
                rbuf[i-1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        CString strRecvData;

        strRecvData.Format("%s\r\n%s %d\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", (const char*)CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"), p, portno, rbuf);
        m_recvData += strRecvData;
        m_bRefershData = true;
        strcat(rbuf, "\r\n");
        send(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        closesocket(clientsocket);
    enter code here
```

i can post the rest of the functions if anyone wants them

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide those compiler errors you get?

In order to connect to a server you just create your socket using a [socket()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, get the socket handler and pass it to the [connect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

It should look something like that on the client side:

```
SOCKET getNewSocket() {
    SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char host[15];
    strcpy(host, "127.0.0.1");
    int port = 80;

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (inet_addr(host) == INADDR_NONE) {
        closesocket(client);
        return NULL;
    }
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    if (connect(client, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
        closesocket(client);
        return NULL;
    }

    return client;
}
```

Comment: yes i have code that creates the socket i just showed the code that is used for the messages. do you want to see the rest of the code?

Comment: the error i get is a dialog box appears when i click the button on the client saying TODO:<File description> has stopped working

Comment: Can you use the debugger to find out which line it crashes on exactly? And one more question. Do you call the [WSAStartup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms742213) function? It is necessary to call it before using socket functions in windows.

Comment: ok i figured out what code to delete to stop the messages but now i want to delete the edit box but when i run the program a dialogbox comes up saying attempting unsupported operations